# fluidrow layout not as expected

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

i am trying to build a  simple shiny application with the  following layout, 2X2 layout

**Data1   Data2

 Stats1   stats2**

```
tabBox(title = "Data Review",id= "ttabs", width = 20, height = "420px",
tabPanel("Data",
column(3, dataTableOutput("data1"))
, column(3, verbatimTextOutput("sum1")),
, column(3, offset = 1,dataTableOutput("data2"))
, column(3, offset = 1, verbatimTextOutput("sum2"))  
)
```

data 2 and stats2 appear as expected (one below the other), however data1 and stat1 appear side by side. Not sure how to update the code to get the expected result

Answer (score 0):

How about use fluidRow()?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
tabBox(title="Data Review", id="ttabs", width=20, height=420,
    tabPanel("Data",
        fluidRow(
            column(6, dataTableOutput("data1")),
            column(6, dataTableOutput("data2")) ),
        fluidRow(
            column(6, verbatimTextOutput("sum1")),
            column(6, verbatimTextOutput("sum2"))  )
    )
)
```

)

I hope this code help you.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.